# Problems with inserting datarows in a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been having problems with inserting datarow in a dataset. I want to insert a row in a dataset then bind it to a gridview control when the user clicks the <kbd>add product</kbd> button but it keeps on giving me an error `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

**My html code**

```
<form runat="server" class="form-horizontal"> <div class="row">

<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Product ID:</label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProdID" class="control-label col-md-3" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Product Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5 input-group">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProducts" runat="server" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Quantity:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-6">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnAddProduct" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" 
                                    Text="Add Product" onclick="btnAddProduct_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </div>   

</div>


<asp:GridView ID="grdPODetails" 
                        class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" runat="server" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="#" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="POQtyOrdered" HeaderText="Quantity" />
                        </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView> </form>
```

c# code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon());
DataSet Details

void GetProducts()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products";
        SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlProducts.DataSource = data;
        ddlProducts.DataTextField = "ProductName";
        ddlProducts.DataValueField = "ProductID";
        ddlProducts.DataBind();
        con.Close();
        lblProdID.Text = ddlProducts.SelectedValue;
    }

void GetPODetails()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PODetails";
        SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        Details = new DataSet();
        data.Fill(Details, "PODetails");
        grdPODetails.DataSource = Details;
        grdPODetails.DataBind();
    }

protected void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dr;
        dr = Details.Tables["PODetails"].NewRow();
        dr["ProductID"] = lblProdID.Text;
        dr["POQtyOrdered"] = txtQty.Text;

        Details.Tables["PODetails"].Rows.Add(dr);
        Details.Tables["PODetails"].AcceptChanges();
        Session["mydataset"] = Details;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, what you are trying to do is,
Get the data set and save it to a public variable called Details. Then you are accessing this variable in the button click event. If you are saving the Details in the !IsPostBack, then it saves the value only during the first postback. 
 You will have to save the Details into session/ViewState
What you can do is create a propert for Details like below

```
DataSet Details
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["mydataset"] != null)
            GetPODetails();
        return Session["mydataset"] as DataSet;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["mydataset"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It still gives me the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: On which line do you get this message?

Comment: I get an error message everytime i click the add product

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object